# Multiple $sum in $group in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given this MongoDB collection:

```
[
  { client: 'client1', type: 'Defect', time: 5 },
  { client: 'client1', type: 'Test', time: 5 },
  { client: 'client2', type: 'Management', time: 3 },
  { client: 'client2', type: 'Defect',     time: 3 },
  { client: 'client3', type: 'Test',     time: 4 }
]
```

I would like to get a sum of times from each issue_type like this:

```
{
  client1:  { 'Defect': 5, 'Test': 5 },
  client2: { 'Management': 3, 'Defect': 3 },
  client3: { 'Test': 4 }
}
```

And I've been trying to do this using the aggregation framework (to replace an existing map/reduce) but have only been able to get as far as getting counts for the combinations like this:

```
{ '_id': { client: 'Client1', class: 'Defect' },  sum: 5 }
{ '_id': { client: 'Client1', class: 'Test' }    count: 5 }
{ '_id': { client: 'Client2', class: 'Management' }, count: 3 } 
{ '_id': { client: 'Client2',     class: 'Defect' },  count: 3 }
{ '_id': { client: 'Client3',     class: 'Test' },  count: 4 }
```

Which is simple enough to reduce programmatically to the desired result but I was hoping to be able to leave that to MongoDB.

For any help that might be rendered many thanks in advance!

Edited

I'm adding this aggregation group

```
db.getCollection('issues').aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group:
            {   
                _id: {component:"$client"},
                totalTime:{$sum: "$time"   }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Your value are string not number. What if you have two documents with same key/value pairs like this `{ client: 'client1', type: 'Defect', time: '5' }`? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you running?

Comment: Please post your aggregation code so we can help you based on what you have so far.

Comment: @user3100115 I want to $sum all hours in client-type. I'm reading a csv with a list of issues time imputation and I want to get some analysis information.

Comment: @Saleem mongod version: 3.0.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't like your suggested output format. What you are essentially asking for 
is taking your "data" and turning that into the "keys" of the result produced. To me this is the antithesis of clean object oriented design, since every "object" is completely different and you basically need to cycle the keys to determine what type of thing it is.

A better approach is to keep the keys as they are, roll-up with [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on the combination of "client" and "type", and then `$group` again to [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) the data per "type" into an array for each grouped "client":

```js
db.getCollection('issues').aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "client": "$client",
            "type": "$type"
        },
        "totalTime": { "$sum": "$time" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.client",
        "data": {
            "$push": {
                "type": "$_id.type",
                "totalTime": "$totalTime"
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

This gives you a result like this:

```js
{
        "_id" : "client1",
        "data" : [
                {
                        "type" : "Test",
                        "totalTime" : 5
                },
                {
                        "type" : "Defect",
                        "totalTime" : 5
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "client2",
        "data" : [
                {
                        "type" : "Defect",
                        "totalTime" : 3
                },
                {
                        "type" : "Management",
                        "totalTime" : 3
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "client3",
        "data" : [
                {
                        "type" : "Test",
                        "totalTime" : 4
                }
        ]
}
```

Which to me is a perfectly natural and structured form of the result with each "client" as a document and a naturally iterable list as it's content.

If you are really insistent on the single object output format with named keys, then this source is easy to transform. And to my mind the simple code shows again how much better the previous result is:

```js
var output = {};

db.getCollection('issues').aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "client": "$client",
            "type": "$type"
        },
        "totalTime": { "$sum": "$time" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.client",
        "data": {
            "$push": {
                "type": "$_id.type",
                "totalTime": "$totalTime"
            }
        }
    }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    output[doc._id] = {};

    doc.data.forEach(function(data) {
        output[doc._id][data.type] = data.totalTime;
    });
});

printjson(output);
```

Then you get your object as you like:

```js
{
        "client1" : {
                "Test" : 5,
                "Defect" : 5
        },
        "client2" : {
                "Defect" : 3,
                "Management" : 3
        },
        "client3" : {
                "Test" : 4
        }
}
```

But if you are really insistent on the server crunching all of the work and not even off-loading the reshaping of the result, then you can always fire this as mapReduce:

```js
db.getCollection('issues').mapReduce(
    function() {
        var output = { },
            data = {};

        data[this.type] = this.time;
        output[this.client] = data;

        emit(null,output)
    },
    function(key,values) {
        var result = {};

        values.forEach(function(value) {
            Object.keys(value).forEach(function(key) { 
                if ( !result.hasOwnProperty(key) )
                    result[key] = {};
                Object.keys(value[key]).forEach(function(dkey) {
                    if ( !result[key].hasOwnProperty(dkey) )
                        result[key][dkey] = 0;
                    result[key][dkey] += value[key][dkey];
                })
            })
        });
        return result;
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Which has the same kind of output:

```js
            {
                    "_id" : null,
                    "value" : {
                            "client1" : {
                                    "Defect" : 5,
                                    "Test" : 5
                            },
                            "client2" : {
                                    "Management" : 3,
                                    "Defect" : 3
                            },
                            "client3" : {
                                    "Test" : 4
                            }
                    }
            }
```

But since it is mapReduce, the interpeted JavaScript is going to run 
much more slowly than the aggregation pipeline's native code, and of course would never scale to a result that produced a document larger than the 16MB BSON limit, because all the result is mashed into one document.

Plus, just look at the complexity of traversing Object keys, checking for keys, creating and adding. It's really just a mess, and an indicator of any further code working with such a structure.

---

So for my money, stay away from transforming perfectly well formed data into something where actual "values" are represented as "keys". It really makes no sense from a clean design perspective, nor does it make since to replace natural lists of "arrays" with traversing the keys of an object.

Comment: Wooooww, fantastic explain and resolve perfectly my question. I don't know about $push operator.